# How to use a temporary variable in the FROM db call?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How do I place a declared temp variable into the FROM and JOIN db commands?

Our SIS holds GPA for each term but class level (and many others) as point-in-time with no history so I can query past DBs to gather information as it was at certain time periods. This means I have to click and type a lot of monotonous strings, so I want to declare a variable for these calls.

I am querying the latter term DB to get certain information and subquery joining the former term DB to get the other, so I'd also like to declare a USE statement for the overall db call too

I currently have, but this is just the latest unsuccessful attempt:

```
DECLARE @term AS VARCHAR(7)
SET @term = 'FA2019';

SELECT GPA blah blah
FROM db AS a
JOIN ( SELECT CLASS_LEVEL blah blah
       FROM FROM [snapshotdb_+@term].[dbo].[sub1]
            JOIN [snapshotdb_+@term].[dbo].[subjoin]
      ) b
where a.STTR_TERM  IN  ( @term  )
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would clarify what you want to do.

Comment: I've run through using it so the data is all fine and verified, it's just that clicking and re-typing and copying/pasting strings for 20 DBs is tedious and annoying. So, I just want to use a declared variable inside the FROM and JOIN commands.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "temporary variable" in SQL Server. This looks like you're trying to use a variable to replace part of an objecst name; that isn't how SQL works. SQL isn't a scripting language. `[DAY10_+@term]` will reference an object literally call `DAY10_+@term`. `@term` won't be replaced by the value contained in the variable `@term`.

Comment: The fact that you want to do this infers you have a design flaw here. You shouldn't have a table for each year (term), you should have a single table, with a column to denote the year(term).

Comment: Also, you have `where a.STTR_TERM  IN  ( @term  )`. Why are you using an `IN` when `@term` is a scalar value?

Comment: You can use table partitioning instead of using manual partitioning with multiple tables. Table partitioning is available in all SQL Server editions, even Express, since 2016 SP1. It used to be an Enterprise-only feature before that. Unless you have several millions of records per year though, no type of partitioning is needed, just proper indexing

Comment: @LordBobbymort you don't need to retype anything. Which SQL Server version are you using? How many records are there per year? Why use multiple tables in the first place?

Comment: @Larnu terms is one table, the student information regarding Class Level is another table. The issue is that, in the production environment, terms_table shows all terms as set in history, so every term a student enrolled in is in one table with their GPAs on each of those rows. But the student_info_table doesn't have this history. The class_level column only shows what is current, so to query information as it stood for each term we hold duplicated DBs at those snapshots.

Comment: @Larnu I copied a set of code from SAP BusinessObjects, which the default filter is IN. It's a string so normally it would have been IN ('FA2019') and I can easily add strings for testing.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it's just the way our Student Information System is setup. There are a lot of tables for a lot of different data regarding students. I have to grab their GPA info from one table and their class level data from another, but the class level is only current information, as in there is only 1 value that can be changed at any time and no history is written in the db. So, I have to query our snapshot DBs from the past to get the class level information for the students status at those time periods for analysis.

Comment: @Larnu, regarding variables. So, I don't know the specific technical names, but I use temp tables and variables and CTEs to deal with different issues all the time trying to query and run analysis on our data. If it works, it works. It already works replacing the strings in Where clauses, or date values in Where clauses, and because these servers don't get queried constantly, I'm not worried about perfect optimization. I just want to see if there is a programatic method of changing values further down the query.

Comment: @LordBobbymort, in the query above you aren't "replacing" `@term` with the value within it. If the value of `@term` was `'FA2019,FA2020'` it wouldn't work as if it was `WHERE term IN ('FA2019','FA2020')`. It would be `WHERE term IN ('FA2019,FA2020')`, which would be identical to `WHERE term = 'FA2019,FA2020'`. Using a variable in the `WHERE` is parameterisation.

Comment: @Larnu I'd comment the declaration if I'm testing, but I'm through with the testing phase, I don't need to filter for multiple terms on the main query, just one at a time. The query works, but I'm changing the WHERE and FROM and JOIN for 19 different runs because I need to requery 19 different snapshot DBs from different past time periods.

Answer (score 0):

use dynamic sql to be able to dynamically use differents databases for you from and inner clauses.

PS:  you also have to put ON clauses for the JOIN

example :

```
DECLARE @term AS VARCHAR(7)
SET @term = 'FA2019';


declare @sql nvarchar(max) = N'
SELECT GPA blah blah
FROM db AS a
JOIN ( SELECT CLASS_LEVEL blah blah
       FROM ' + quotename('snapshotdb_' + @TERM) + '.[dbo].[sub1]
            JOIN ' + quotename('snapshotdb_' + @TERM) + '.[dbo].[subjoin]
      ) b
where a.STTR_TERM  IN  ( ' + replace(@term,'''','''''') + '  )

';

exec (@sql);
```

Comment: Careful, this is wide open to injection. `@term` should be properly parametrised in the `WHERE` and properly quoted (using `QUOTENAME`) in the `FROM`.

Comment: @Larnu right, fixed..... but in this case, useless cause it's an hard-coded value from the code, not a parameter.  but i understand what  you mean

Comment: `@term` in the `WHERE` still need to be parametrisef.

Comment: That isn't parametrising. It should be `'... where a.STTR_TERM = @term;';` and then you use `sys.sp_executesql` to pass `@term` to the dynamic statement.

Comment: @Larnu I am just querying directly using SSMS, should I still worry about injection? This doesn't sit on an external or internal webpage or via any other software

Comment: *"should I still worry about injection?"* Always.

Comment: @Larnu yes, the sentiment is there, but I can't find anything anywhere else about injection on direct queries vis SSMS as opposed to web forms, APIs, etc.

Comment: The platform you are using doesn't change if SQL is open to injection, @LordBobbymort . A query that is open to injection is open to injection, regardless of if you are executing the statement from a IDE (i.e. SSMS), a programming language (i.e. C#), command line (i.e. powershell), etc, etc, etc.